# Calculation of the greatest fall in the river

Tags: python, gdal, geopandas, rasterio, fiona

I have a task to write a Python program using the 'gdal', 'geopandas', 'reasterio' and 'fiona' libraries. This program is to calculate the greatest fall in the river (height difference between the source and the mouth). I have no idea how I could do this task in terms of data, I have to use the rivers layer and the demo.

Comment: You need to add a code attempt or your question will get closed

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. If you (who have access to the data) don't know what to do, then it's unlikely that we (who haven't been told what data is available), can help. You need to [Edit] the Question so that the necessary information is available, and because it's a coding Question, provide the the code you've tested so far, with a description of the problem you have encountered.